# Icinga2 client RHEL7 powerppc

Tags: redhat

I gave icinga2 monitoring server in x86 but I have also IBM plc64le servers with RHEL7.3 the problem is there is no icinga2 package for redhat ppc64le only for deb based distos

Any idea if there is a way to monitor those servers I plan to create docker icinga2 client based on Debian in privileged mode. Any other opinions.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can build RPM for ppc64le
https://github.com/Icinga/icinga2/blob/master/INSTALL.md

```
[root@rhel7-dev-env-template ppc64le]# ls -l
total 26896
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    28768 Oct 30 00:29 icinga2-2.10.1-1.el7.ppc64le.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3319612 Oct 30 00:29 icinga2-bin-2.10.1-1.el7.ppc64le.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   139488 Oct 30 00:29 icinga2-common-2.10.1-1.el7.ppc64le.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 20184944 Oct 30 00:29 icinga2-debuginfo-2.10.1-1.el7.ppc64le.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3555724 Oct 30 00:29 icinga2-doc-2.10.1-1.el7.ppc64le.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   107060 Oct 30 00:29 icinga2-ido-mysql-2.10.1-1.el7.ppc64le.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   106960 Oct 30 00:29 icinga2-ido-pgsql-2.10.1-1.el7.ppc64le.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    55228 Oct 30 00:29 icinga2-selinux-2.10.1-1.el7.ppc64le.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     5672 Oct 30 00:29 nano-icinga2-2.10.1-1.el7.ppc64le.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     8412 Oct 30 00:29 vim-icinga2-2.10.1-1.el7.ppc64le.rpm
[root@rhel7-dev-env-template ppc64le]#

[root@rhel7-dev-env-template ppc64le]# systemctl status icinga2
● icinga2.service - Icinga host/service/network monitoring system
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/icinga2.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
```